# Writing the model on lp file cplex and C++

Tags: optimization, visual-c++, model, cplex

I have coded the following constraint in C++ and solving the problem by Calling cplex solver:

```
for (IloInt p = 0; p < 3; ++p) {
    for (IloInt t = 0; t < 6; ++t) {
      IloExpr v(env);
      for (IloInt m = 0; m < 5; ++m)
           v += X[p][m][t];
    model.add(v == K[p][t]);
    v.end();
}
 }
```

What I expect:

```
X[1][1][1]+X[1][2][1]+X[1][3][1]+X[1][4][1]+X[1][5][1]=K[1][1]
```

However, when I export the .lp file , I get:
I get:

```
c1: x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 = constant

c2: x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 = constant

c3: x11 + x12 + x13 + x14 + x15 = constant

…...………………………………..………

………………...……......………..….

c18: x86 + x87 + x88 + x89 + x90 = quantity
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To set the name of x[1][2] to x[1][2] you can write:

```
x[1][2].setName("x[1][2]");
```

Comment: Hello @Alex, thank you so much for answering me . I have many variables in the model , I thought the Following definition wil be useful , is is not it correct ? Look:

Comment: Hello @Alex, thank you so much, I solved the problem with the hint you gave me , thank you

Comment: As a general comment, naming your variables and constraints with sensible names that you recongise is unbelievably useful when you want to debug or check your model. Definitely recommend doing that.